# Android Color Convert setColorFilter

Tags: android, colors

I need to use a HTML color code I have in my app.

I am using:

```
ProgressBar downloadProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.downloadprogress);
downloadProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
    0xFFFF0000,
    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
);
```

I need to convert a HTML colour code to the format above (like 0xFFFF0000.)

How do I do that? Or is there another solution for using a HTML color code with the above code?

Comment: Just a technical thing, there is no such a thing as HTML color code. What you meant is Hexadecimal color: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29788/color-hex-code

Answer (score 12):

### You can use like:

```
ProgressBar downloadProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.downloadprogress);
downloadProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"),android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I think it will help you.
Thank you.